# data extraction: pandas column operations

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame in this format

```
Col1|Col2
A|Agriculture, forestry and fishing
1|Crop and animal production, hunting and related service activities
11|Growing of non-perennial crops
12|Growing of perennial crops
14|Animal production
C|Manufacturing
11|Manufacture of beverages
110|Manufacture of beverages
12|Manufacture of tobacco products
120|Manufacture of tobacco products 
14|Manufacture of wearing apparel 
141|Manufacture of wearing apparel, except fur apparel
```

A is Item | Under A it is 1 Sub Item and below it is 11 which is sub_sub_item. 
Problem comes when there is 11 as Sub Item under 'C'

for now i have done the following:

```
Col0_list = df['Col0'].values.tolist()
Col1_list = df['Col1'].values.tolist()

#Defining Empty lists
item = []
sub_item = []
sub_sub = []
#looping through the 
for i in range(len(Col0_list)):
if str(Col0_list[i]).isalpha():
    item.append(Col1_list[i])
    sub_item.append(np.nan)
    sub_sub.append(np.nan)
elif Col0_list[i] < 10 and len(str(Col0_list[i]))==1:
    item.append(np.nan)
    sub_item.append(Col1_list[i])
    sub_sub.append(np.nan)
elif icode_list[i] > 10 and len(str(Col0_list[i]))== 2:
#THIS IS WHERE IT FAILS SINCE '11' is both sub_item and sub_sub
```

I wish to convert this into the format as below

```
Item|SubItem|Sub-SubItem
Agriculture, forestry and fishing|Crop and animal production, hunting and related service activities|Growing of non-perennial crops
Agriculture, forestry and fishing|Crop and animal production, hunting and related service activities|Growing of perennial crops
Agriculture, forestry and fishing|Crop and animal production, hunting and related service activities|Animal production
Manufacturing|Manufacture of beverages|Manufacture of beverages
Manufacturing|Manufacture of tobacco products|Manufacture of tobacco products 
Manufacturing|Manufacture of wearing apparel |Manufacture of wearing apparel, except fur apparel
```

Comment: how do u know which is sub item and sub sub items? is it always the first item after the letter that is the sub item and all others follow? the output from Agriculture is quite different from that in Manufacturing

Comment: yes, it is always in such format. 

Alphabet A - item, 1 SubItem, 11 Sub-SubItem
Alphabet C-item, 11 SubItem, 110 Sub-SubItem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not imagine a nice vectorized way, so I would just loop over the Col1 data to discover whether the row is an Item, SubItem or SubSubItem. And I would use that to build the resulting dataframe:

```
typ=np.zeros(len(df))
for i, key in enumerate(df['Col1']):
    if re.match('[A-Z]+', key, re.I):
        prev = key
    elif key.startswith(prev):
        typ[i] = 2
    else:
        typ[i] = 1
        prev = key

resul = pd.DataFrame(index = df.index, columns=['Item', 'SubItem', 'SubSubItem'])

for i in range(3):
    resul.iloc[:, i] = df.loc[typ == i, 'Col2']
```

It gives:

```
                                 Item                                            SubItem                                         SubSubItem
0   Agriculture, forestry and fishing                                                NaN                                                NaN
1                                 NaN  Crop and animal production, hunting and relate...                                                NaN
2                                 NaN                                                NaN                     Growing of non-perennial crops
3                                 NaN                                                NaN                         Growing of perennial crops
4                                 NaN                                                NaN                                  Animal production
5                       Manufacturing                                                NaN                                                NaN
6                                 NaN                           Manufacture of beverages                                                NaN
7                                 NaN                                                NaN                           Manufacture of beverages
8                                 NaN                    Manufacture of tobacco products                                                NaN
9                                 NaN                                                NaN                    Manufacture of tobacco products
10                                NaN                     Manufacture of wearing apparel                                                NaN
11                                NaN                                                NaN  Manufacture of wearing apparel, except fur app...
```

We have just to fill NaN values and filter the relevant rows

```
resul = resul.ffill()[typ == 2].reset_index(drop=True)
```

to get:

```
                                Item                                            SubItem                                         SubSubItem
0  Agriculture, forestry and fishing  Crop and animal production, hunting and relate...                     Growing of non-perennial crops
1  Agriculture, forestry and fishing  Crop and animal production, hunting and relate...                         Growing of perennial crops
2  Agriculture, forestry and fishing  Crop and animal production, hunting and relate...                                  Animal production
3                      Manufacturing                           Manufacture of beverages                           Manufacture of beverages
4                      Manufacturing                    Manufacture of tobacco products                    Manufacture of tobacco products
5                      Manufacturing                     Manufacture of wearing apparel  Manufacture of wearing apparel, except fur app...
```

Answer (score 0):

use this method:

```
data = [['tom', 10,'M'], ['nick', 15,'M'], ['juli', 14,'F']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Age','Gender'])

json_records = df.to_dict('records')

req_json = {}
male_list = []
female_list = []

for item in json_records:
    if item['Gender'] == 'M':
        male_list.append(item['Name'])
    if item['Gender'] == 'F':
        female_list.append(item['Name'])
    req_json['males'] = male_list
    req_json['females'] = female_list
print(req_json)
```

Answer (score 0):

Though a bit complex, but the following snippet of code does the job.

```
##### Fetching Col1 indices with String value
string_inndices=[]
for idx,col in enumerate(df['Col1']):
    try:
        int(df.iloc[idx,0])
        #print('Integer')
    except:
        #print('String')
        string_inndices.append(idx)



integer_lengths=[]

for i in range(len(string_inndices)):
    try:
        k=string_inndices[i+1]
        integer_lengths.extend(list(map(lambda x:len(str(x)),df.iloc[string_inndices[i]:string_inndices[i+1],0])))
        first_length=integer_lengths[string_inndices[i]+1]
        first_index=string_inndices[i]+1
        Rows=[]
        for item in range(string_inndices[i]+1,string_inndices[i+1]):
            if integer_lengths[item]>first_length:
                row = [df.iloc[string_inndices[i],1],df.iloc[first_index,1],df.iloc[item,1]]
                Rows.append(row)
            elif integer_lengths[item]==first_length:
                first_index=item
        #print(Rows)
    except:
        integer_lengths.extend(list(map(lambda x:len(str(x)),df.iloc[string_inndices[i]:,0])))
        first_length=integer_lengths[string_inndices[i]+1]
        first_index=string_inndices[i]+1
        for item in range(string_inndices[i]+1,len(df)):
            #print(df.iloc[item,1])
            if integer_lengths[item]>first_length:
                row = [df.iloc[string_inndices[i],1],df.iloc[first_index,1],df.iloc[item,1]]
                Rows.append(row)
            elif integer_lengths[item]==first_length:
                #print(first_length)
                first_index=item
        #print(Rows)

df_new = pd.DataFrame(data=Rows,columns=['Item','SubItem','Sub-SubItem'])
```

Output table looks like

```
Item    SubItem Sub-SubItem
0   Agriculture, forestry and fishing   Crop and animal production, hunting and relate...   Growing of non-perennial crops
1   Agriculture, forestry and fishing   Crop and animal production, hunting and relate...   Growing of perennial crops
2   Agriculture, forestry and fishing   Crop and animal production, hunting and relate...   Animal production
3   Manufacturing   Manufacture of beverages    Manufacture of beverages
4   Manufacturing   Manufacture of tobacco products Manufacture of tobacco products
5   Manufacturing   Manufacture of wearing apparel  Manufacture of wearing apparel, except fur app...
```